# How to match x number of characters of a file name with cp?

Tags: regular-expression, cp

I try to use `cp` to copy a file with a partially dynamic name:

```
cp google71bg2z2850dafxa3.html DESTIONATION
```

By principle, the `google` part of the file name is consistent, but the `71bg2z2850dafxa3` (16 characters) part of the file name is dynamic and I don't want to manually change it in any script, if I don't have to, so I thought about using regex.

In `man cp` I didn't find any data on "regex" or "regular expressions".
Also, I have tried `cp x{2} DESTINATION` for a file named `x12`, which failed.

How to match x number of characters of a file name with cp?

<sub>That is to ask; how could I match the 16 characters with some regex?</sub>

Comment: @Theophrastus I am familiar with it to some extent and can post a link to my github own "pocket manual" about it but I want to ensure I match only 16 characters afterwards.

Comment: @Theophrastus I now recall these from a regex course a few years back, I didn't know it is part of the shell glob system; this might be best although I want to match only numbers and English letters without special symbols.

Comment: Yes, just time and again I am surprised by the amount of overlapping; I think it will be helpful to wrap these options into an answer which I will gladly accept and upvote.

Comment: `cp google????????????????.html DESTIONATION` [sic]

Comment: @pizdelect yes, Theophrastus suggested that but from some reason deleted his (or hers) comments.

Comment: There is also nothing on globs in the `cp` manual -- it is not `cp`s job, to glob or regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a simplification, but if all of the files in which you're interested are in a single directory, and if none of those files have spaces in their names, you could do something like:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
destination="/wherever"
for i in *; do
    if echo "${i}" | grep -q -E '^google.{16}\.html$'; then
        cp "${i}" "${destination}"
    fi
done
```

Here I'm using `grep` to do the regex matching: File names that begin (`^`) with `google`, followed by any 16 characters (`.{16}`), followed by `.html` at the end (`$`) of the name.

Bash also supports the regex matching too, so you could also do this with:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
destination="/wherever"
for i in *; do
    if [[ "${i}" =~ ^google.{16}\.html$ ]]; then
        cp "${i}" "${destination}"
    fi
done
```

The regex here is the same as my previous example.